# How to calculate the factorial of any number through recursion method

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, factorial

I code this through recursion method. This code is calculating the factorial of any number. I run this code and its create exception. I have any logical error. How can I correct this?

```java
package factorial;

public class Factorial {

    int i=1; 

    public int fact(int f){
        return i*fact(f-1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Factorial fa=new Factorial();
        fa.fact(5);
        System.out.println(fa.i);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the base case(case 0) of this problem, Please try below method to calculate factorial:

```
static int fact(int n) 
{ 
    if (n == 0) 
      return 1; 

    return n * fact(n-1); 
}
```

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you explained why the OP's code throws an exception (infinite recursion), and then explain how your code avoids that problem.

Comment: thanks @JimMischel, edited it with the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```java
package factorial;

public class Factorial {

    public int fact(int f){
        if(f == 0)
           return 1;
        return f * fact(f-1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Factorial fa=new Factorial();
        int factorial = fa.fact(5);
        System.out.println(factorial);
    }

}
```